# How can I validate my curve fitting meta-regression?

Tags: p-value, validation, curve-fitting, meta-regression

I'm doing a meta-regression analysis on Normal Pressure Hydrocephalus Gait Analysis. Studying the variation of gait velocity after a procedure (Tap-test). Keeping into account single study (#14) variation (POST-PRE) I have built up a regression curve. How do I validate this curve? what parameter can I use, something like p-value or similar? I have done this curve fitting with a smoothing spline model.